# JPA update query: cache not properly invalidated

Tags: jpa, caching, eclipselink

Why doesn't it work:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test-pu");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    String id = "id";
    long value = 1234L;

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    FancyEntity fancyEntity = new FancyEntity(id);
    entityManager.persist(fancyEntity);
    int updateCount = entityManager.createQuery("update FancyEntity item set item.value = ?2 where item.id = ?1").setParameter(1, id).setParameter(2, value).executeUpdate();
    assertEquals(1, updateCount);

    FancyEntity checkResult = entityManager.find(FancyEntity.class, id);
    assertEquals(1234L, checkResult.getValue()); // <- this assert fails

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

with

```
@Entity
public class FancyEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Column
    private long value;
    public FancyEntity(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = 0;
    }
    public FancyEntity() {
    }
    public long getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

and

```
<persistence-unit name="test-pu"
                  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.fancypackage.FancyEntity</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="SEVERE"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem;sql.enforce_strict_size=true;hsqldb.tx=mvcc" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Result is

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :1234
Actual   :0
```

It seems there is some cache that is not invalidated by the update query. `checkResult` and `fancyEntity` are the same object. Forcing the refresh using `entityManager.refresh(checkResult)`. The weirdest thing is that a `select` is issued for retrieving `checkResult` (seen in the eclipselink log), still its result is not taken into account. Same behavior using MySQL rather than HSQL.

Any hint on what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a bulk update statement,  As the JPQL language reference notes:

> **The persistence context is not synchronized with the result of the
>   bulk update or delete**. Caution should be used when executing bulk
>   update or delete operations because they **may result in inconsistencies
>   between the database and the entities in the active persistence
>   context**. In general, bulk update and delete operations should only be
>   performed within a separate transaction or at the beginning of a
>   transaction (before entities have been accessed whose state might be
>   affected by such operations).

https://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_bulk_ops)

So the behaviour you are seeing makes perfect sense.